# Is Xamarin UITableView Source weak or strong?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, xamarin, weak

Can this cause a memory leak in `C#` Xamarin or not? i.e. can MyViewController be released or does it have a circular reference, preventing it?

In MyViewController:

```cs
this.TableView.Source = new ViewSource(this);


public class ViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private readonly MyViewController parentController;

    public ViewSource(MyViewController parentController)
    {
        this.parentController=parentController;
    }
}
```

According to:

[Will a UITableViewController Garbage Collect if it instances a nested class referencing itself in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258885/will-a-uitableviewcontroller-garbage-collect-if-it-instances-a-nested-class-refe) it is not a problem. But if Source is a weak, then what happens if you just have:

```cs
this.TableView.Source = new ViewSource();
```

Source can be released from the next line? Either way this seems a very dangerous API.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will probably said it better than me, but in a few words: Don't worry about your second case. `GC` issues happens mainly on Xamarin.iOS if you have cycles in managed object that have a strong relation in their `obj-C` counterparts.

In your (2nd) case, the newly created `ViewSource` will be kept alive as long as the `TableView` lives. I'm speaking about managed objects here. At the time the `TableView` is no longer used, Xamarin.iOS `GC` will flag it, as well as the `ViewSource`, and they both will be disposed.

That's unfortunately one of the few Leaky Abstraction of Xamarin.iOS, where you need some knowledge of the underlying Obj-C to make a design decision.